# Firebase ui Popup is not working in chrome extension Manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, firebaseui

This is the error I am getting while inspecting `popup.js`:

```
firebase-auth.js:1 Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb916487' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

La @ firebase-auth.js:1
firebase-auth.js:1 Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb916487' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

La @ firebase-auth.js:1
firebase-auth.js:1 Uncaught Error: Network Error
    at firebase-auth.js:1:97145
    at e.b (firebase-auth.js:1:28705)
    at De (firebase-auth.js:1:29689)
    at Ce (firebase-auth.js:1:29559)
    at pe.t.ec (firebase-auth.js:1:30399)
    at de (firebase-auth.js:1:27468)
```

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2. I'm facing the same error. did you find a solution?

Comment: With the release of manifest v3, you can't use popup operations anymore with chrome extension. That's mentionned in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk#other_environments): "All Authentication features, except phone authentication and popup/redirect OAuth operations, are supported.". There are [some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70983111/10377302) to go over it though.