# manifest version 3 doesn't play nicely with Google signin

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My extension will be using manifest version 3, since version 2 will no longer be supported beginning 2023. However, the extension also will make use of Google signin and passwordless email signin and I found the following issue (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin):

"Only popup operations (signInWithPopup, linkWithPopup, and reauthenticateWithPopup) are available to Chrome extensions, as Chrome extensions cannot use HTTP redirects. You should call these methods from a background page script rather than a browser action popup, as the authentication popup will cancel the browser action popup."

The popup methods may only be used in extensions using Manifest V2. The newer Manifest V3 only allows background scripts in the form of service workers, which cannot perform the popup operations at all. How can I implement Google signin in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase 3rd-party AuthProvider (Google/Facebook/etc) login with chrome extension manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311559/firebase-3rd-party-authprovider-google-facebook-etc-login-with-chrome-extensio)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for the link!